# Duplicate Records when they should be unique

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that I'm trying to query using Linq to SQL

The table is very simple it has 5 columns:

```
 - PersonID
 - ADID
 - Name
 - PlaceID
 - PlaceName
```

I have 2 records in my table and they have the same PersonID in both records but different PlaceID and PlaceName values:

```
001 | 001 | Person X | P01 | Place 1
001 | 001 | Person X | P02 | Place 2
```

When I query this in SQL I get exactly the 2 rows:

```
select * from myTable where PersonID = '001'
```

However, when I try to do it in LINQ:

```
List<myTable> PersonInfo = (from myInfo in db.myTable 
where myInfo.PersonID == "001"
select myInfo).ToList();
```

I get a count of 2 in `PersonInfo` but they are the same record.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How are you outputting the data, or are you inspecting with the debugger?

Comment: @KeithPayne - yes I'm using the debugger

Comment: This is a head-scratcher. Is there anything weird going on in `PersonInfo`? Wherever the problem lies, it doesn't appear to be in this code that you posted. Maybe post a lot more of the code and something will jump out.

Comment: Do you have a PK or unique index defined on the table with the two columns (PersonID, PlaceID)? Is it possible that you are connecting to a different database than you expect?

Comment: I am using EF 5 - Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @KeithPayne - I just checked there is only a EntityKey and that is on the LoginID

Comment: Show the mapping. EF uses several "conventions" and has probably decided that PersonId is a primary key.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - How do I show the mapping?  The edmx image or something else?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Still, that wouldn't seem to cause this issue.

Comment: Yes, if it was db-first then post (parts of) the EDMX or a screenshot. @KeithPayne - I'm not sure how he caching deals with this but you're probably right.

Comment: This is typical for cases where a non-unique primary key is defined in the EF model. How would you identify the records when writing plain SQL?

Comment: @GertArnold - What do you mean?  I wrote a simple SQL statement above and it works..

Comment: Sure, the question is: how do you *uniquely* identify records? By which fields do *you* know that two records are different? EF should have those fields as primary key.

Comment: @GertArnold - Well technically the table was setup to have duplicate rows (specifically in my example)  where 1 person can have 2 places.  I suppose I could recommend adding an identity field...  Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @GertArnold - When I added an Identity column on the table and updated my model it worked...  I guess my question is, is there a way around this so I don't have to change the DB Schema?

Comment: I think you really should change the schema. The basis of the relational model is that each field in a record only has a relation with the primary key (that's what relational means), so the PK uniquely identifies a row. There can't be two identical rows, else the whole building falls apart. Only adding a unique key is not enough for you. You should *normalize* your model first, i.e. create a Person table and a `Place` table having a foreign key to `Person` (and more, I suspect).

Comment: Yea I think Entity Framework barfs spectacularly when your model doesn't have a primary key.  Best to just fix the DB and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out was that 1st Entity Framework needs a primary key to operate correctly.  After researching the table I was using I found out that there was a primary key but it was a combo key  So once I put "Entity Keys" on both columns my select statement returned the correct data.

Thanks to @GertArnold and everyone else that helped me on this problem!

Comment: Still I think you should normalize the data model. What if you want to fetch Persons only?